# NSTableView not Populating

Tags: cocoa, nsarray, nstableview

I've been trying to get this NSTableView to populate for the last 7 hours. I am trying to get a list of all the currently running application and put them into an NSTableView. Eventually I would like to parse the resultes and organize the PID in one column and the Application Bundle in the other. I am getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on " return [listOfWindows objectAtIndex:row];"  I am currently using Xcode 4.3.2 and running OS X Lion 10.7.4.  Thanks in advance everyone!

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet NSMenu *statusMenu;
    IBOutlet NSButton *button;
    IBOutlet NSWindow *menuWindow;
    IBOutlet NSTableView *proTable;
    NSArray *listOfWindows;
    IBOutlet NSArrayController *arrayController;
    AppDelegate *mainMenu;
    NSWorkspace  *workSpace;

    NSStatusItem *statusItem;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

-(IBAction)loadConfig:(id)sender;
@end

#import "AppDelegate.h"
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize window = _window;


- (void) awakeFromNib
{   
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                                         selector:@selector(loadMenu:) 
                                                              name:@"WhiteBox"
                                                      object:nil];
[self addStatusItem];

 //[proTable setDataSource:self];

listOfWindows = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications];
NSLog(@"index %@", listOfWindows);

int y = 0;
y = [listOfWindows count];
NSLog(@"y = %d", y);

[proTable setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];   
    }

-(void)applicationWillTerminate
{
    NSLog(@"Will Terminate");
}


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

}


-(void)applicationDidResignActive:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Resign Active");

}

-(void) addStatusItem
{
    //Create a variable length status item from the system statusBar
    statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
    [statusItem retain];

//Set a Title for it
[statusItem setTitle:@"Status Item"];

    //Set an Image and an alternate image
    //[statusItem setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"lnc"]];
    //[statusItem setAlternateImage: [NSImage imageNamed:@"status"]];

    //Add a Tool Tip
    [statusItem setToolTip:@"Status Item Tooltip"];

    //Choose to highlight the item when clicked
    [statusItem setHighlightMode:YES];

    //To Trigger a method on click use the following two lines of code
[statusItem setMenu:statusMenu];
    //[statusItem setAction:@selector(loadMenu:)];

}

-(IBAction)loadConfig:(id)sender
{

    if(! [menuWindow isVisible] )
    {
        [menuWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:sender];
    } else {
        [menuWindow performClose:sender];
    }

}


- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
{
    return [listOfWindows count];
}
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView 
objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn 
            row:(NSInteger)row
{
    return [listOfWindows objectAtIndex:row];
}



@end
```

Answer (score 0):

What object is the table view's data source? I don't see any object in the source you posted as implementing the [`NSTableViewDataSource` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSTableDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Further, have you tried putting breakpoints in the various data source methods to see if the debugger stops in them? If not, it's usually a good sign that your data source isn't connected to your table view.

Comment: I have the data source connected to AppDelegate in IB

Comment: But you haven't declared anything as implementing the `NSTableViewDataSource` protocol. If the code internal to `NSTableView` does a runtime check like `if ([_dataSource conformsToProtocol:@protocol(NSTableViewDataSource)]) {...` then it will never call your code. Have you put a breakpoint in your data source methods to see if they're actually getting called?

Answer (score 0):

I got: -[NSRunningApplication copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector error when I ran your code.  This could be fixed by changing your return line in tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row: to

return [[listOfWindows objectAtIndex:row]localizedName];

NSRunningApplication doesn't conform to NSCopying, so I don't know if you can put instances of that class in a table view.  However, you can get its properties like localizedName, processIdentifier, and bundleIdentifier.

I've run into this problem before with classes that don't implement NSCopying, I'd be happy to know if anyone knows a way to use these classes in table views or outline views.